# google docs linked charts refresh with api or apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I have a google doc that I show inside an iframe in my website for **public editing**, it contains linked charts from a public spreadsheet,

I change the chart data with spreadsheet api, but the chart in the doc does not refresh automatically, and I can't clic update or update all in the doc because the "**update button**" is disabled,

SO I wanted to use google docs api or apps script to refresh charts,
I did not find how to do it with **google docs api**, and **apps script** does not trigger inside the iframe,

Can you please give me any idea how to do this,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to refresh charts programatically in a Google Document. You should definitely [submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features) a feature request for `SheetsChart` support as there is in [Google Slide App Script Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/sheets-chart).

### Workaround with Slides

Since the update feature is currently available for Slides you could achieve to style a Slide as a document and use it in your iFrame. Following this update logic you will be able to trigger a SheetsChart refresh every minute for example:

```
function myFunction() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('updateCharts').timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();
}

function updateCharts() {
  let slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
  slides.forEach(slide => {
                 let charts = slide.getSheetsCharts();
                 charts.forEach(chart=> chart.refresh());
                 });
}
```

### Workaround with Documents

However, since your goal is to provide your website viewers with the last version of the iFrame this can be done automatically on Document save:

`File > Publish on the Web > check Automatically republish when changes are made`

You will have to update manually the chart in your Document though. But this change will be reflected in your webpage automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,
Actually I don't update the charts data manually, I do it through google spreadsheet API triggered by the client's click, that's why I needed to refresh the linked charts in the doc automatically

Comment: Then there is no way to update a chart in a document automatically it at the moment. You could use a Google Slide App though, I think that if you style it properly you will achieve the same results.