# How to insert an embedded sheet via Google Docs API?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to insert an embedded Google Sheets table into a Google Doc via the Google Doc API. I had hoped that I could do this via an [EmbeddedObject](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/EmbeddedObject). The definition of EmbeddedObject includes a field for [LinkedContentReference](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/EmbeddedObject#LinkedContentReference), but despite the generic name, a LinkedContentReference object seems to refer only to a Sheets chart.

Is there a way to embed a Sheets table in a Google Doc via API?

I did notice that Google Sheets offers a Table Chart as a chart type. This may be an effective workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need to insert the sheet table as an [inline image](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#insertinlineimagerequest)

> [An InlineObject contains an EmbeddedObject such as an image.](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/InlineObject)

- Now, when you publish a Google Sheets, you have the option to publish it as pdf, but not image. This mean that you would need to perform an additional step of converting the pdf into a supported image format.
- Alternatively you can obtain (and save on your Drive) the Sheet as a `thumbNail` by performing a [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) request on the Sheet and setting `fields` to `thumbnailLink`. Mind that the thumbNail contians the whole sheet view - not only the data range.

**Important:**

When performing a [documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) request [InsertInlineImageRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#insertinlineimagerequest), you need to specify the `uri` in the format

`https://docs.google.com/uc?export=view&id=PASTE_HERE_YOUR_ID`

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on whether the Table Chart approach would work? Can't say I'm a fan of the idea of turning data into an image.

Comment: If you use the Table Chart approach, you can directly export the table to an image instead of pdf. Also, Google Slides features the [CreateSheetsChartRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#createsheetschartrequest), but Google Docs unfortunately does not so far, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794107/google-docs-linked-charts-refresh-with-api-or-apps-script). So as of now, there is no way of embedding an interactive chart / table programamtically from Google Sheets to Google Docs.